# How to pass RequestParam in POST request using REST Assured

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

Here is Dev rest client POST request sudocode

```
public ResponseDTO upload(@RequestParam("metadata") String metaData, 
    @RequestParam(name="file" , required=false) MultipartFile[] multiPartFiles)
```

I am trying to create a POST request using restassured. Below is my code of step definitation

```
 public void havePostCall(String endpoint) {
            String url = be.getBaseUrl()+endpoint;
            FileInputStream fisFile = new FileInputStream(new File("Path of the json file"));
            String reqPayload = IOUtils.toString(fisFile,"UTF-8");
            Response rs = RestAssured.given().header("Authorization","value of token") 
               .queryParam("metadata",reqPayload).when().post(url).then().assertThat().statusCode(200)

                .extract()
                .response () 
           System.out.print("Response is ==" + rs.asString())
          }
```

as we can see dev rest client upload method is expecting Request Param in the POST Request and in my Rest assured code I am passing the same but I still keep on getting BAD request.
When I check with dev they say pass body as a Request Param.
Can some one please help me what wrong I am doing in my step definiation code?
Strugging quite long time any help much appreciated.

Comment: `.queryParam("metadata",reqPayload)`--> Is `reqPayload`  a `String`?

Comment: @NandanA If you observe Rest client which is written by Dev is accepting  Request Param in the payload for POST request. Yes, it is String metaData.

Comment: Can you please try the below provided solution?

Comment: Trying. give me time will post an answer.

Comment: Could you provide request log? is there anything wrong with your string in query param?

Comment: The request body is a JSON. Have kept that in file and from there I am reading. is that you want to see?

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: no, this is not resolved yet. dev team saying string has to go and I am very well converting requestbody into string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved. The issue was the key which is passing in `queryParam`.

```
Response rs = RestAssured.given().header("Authorization","value of token") 
    .queryParam("metaData",reqPayload).when().post(url).then().assertThat().statusCode(200)
    .extract()
    .response () 
System.out.print("Response is ==" + rs.asString())
```